# Передача логов по сети

Tags: java, веб-программирование, логирование

Есть ли готовая реализация для передачи логов из java веб приложения по сети на другой сервер? Или это делается как обычная передача файлов через сокет? В смысле, может быть есть уже какая-то готовая библиотека для этого?

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не записывать в БД логи?

Comment: Объясню, если приложение будем скомпромитировано то мне хотелось бы иметь логи на другом сервере (которые, не могут быть изменены)

Comment: Те логи будут храниться, как в бд на сервере так и на другом сервере удалённо

Comment: Объясните, в чем для вас разница между хранением лога в удаленной БД или в хранении на удаленном сервере по средствам написания какого то сервиса для приема логов.

Comment: Да, об этом я не подумал, что можно просто хранить логи в удалённой бд, спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зависит от того, чем вы пользуетесь для логирования.

- Для Logback, например, существуют [SocketAppender и SSLSocketAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender) для отправки событий по сети, [SyslogAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) для отправки на Syslog-сервер.

  Сервер для логирования через SocketAppender настраивается обычными средствами (XML) и запускается просто из командной строки:

  ```
  java ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SimpleSocketServer 6000 \
  src/main/java/chapters/appenders/socket/server1.xml
  ```
- В Log4j 2 реализованы JMSAppender / KafkaAppender / ZeroMQ Appender для прокачки логов через очереди и аналогичные упомянутым выше SocketAppender и SyslogAppender.

Comment: Про сислог очень актуально, спасибо